# javascript remove chars

Tags: javascript, string

I have

`var content='<td>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                some_html_code
            </td>
            <td>
                another_html
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>'`

How to remove `<td>` at beginning and `</td>` in the end?

Comment: Assuming you're using JavaScript on the client-side, you have the DOM available to you, which means this can be done without fiddling with HTML strings. Where exactly does this string come from? The document? - If so, use the DOM to reference and retrieve the `<table>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simpley `slice()` to obtain a copy of a portion of a string.

```
  var tmp_start_td = content.slice(5);

  var tmp_end_td = tmp_start_td.slice(0,-6);

  content = tmp_end_td; // result
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
content.replace(/^<td>\s?(.+)\s?<\/td>$/, "$1")
```

Edit: or similarly:

```
content.replace(/^<td>/, "").replace(/<\/td>$/, "")
```

Comment: Why? This is complete overkill.

Comment: Each to his own of course, but I think the advantage of doing this is readability: it's fairly apparent what you're trying to do at a glance. I've added an alternative, that's perhaps a little simpler.

Comment: hello, i wanted the same , but how can i remove td with attributes? eg:<td class="myclass"...... etc.....</td> and also &nbsp should be replaced with space

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that string is all you've got:

```
newcontent = content.substr(4,content.length-5);
```

is the simplest method. If you're trying to get this out of a larger body of html (an entire page?) then I'd suggest using DOM operations instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an XML parser, or DOM manipulation methods:

```
// Using DOM manipulation methods
var myEl = document.createElement("tr");
myEl.innerHTML = "<td>\n"+
                 "    <table>\n" +
                 "    <tr>\n" +
                 "        <td>\n" +
                 "            some_html_code\n" +
                 "        </td>\n" +
                 "        <td>\n" +
                 "            another_html\n" +
                 "        </td>\n" +
                 "    </tr>\n" +
                 "    </table>\n" +
                 "</td>";
var out = myEl.childNodes[0].innerHTML;

console.log(out);
```

One of the benefits of using the DOM methods above is that they can be more forgiving of validation/well-formedness errors... but as a result they might add a `<tbody>` element to the markup.

Alternately, you could also use the less-forgiving [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser):

```
// using the DOMParser to parse XML
var content = "<td>\n"+
              "    <table>\n" +
              "    <tr>\n" +
              "        <td>\n" +
              "            some_html_code\n" +
              "        </td>\n" +
              "        <td>\n" +
              "            another_html\n" +
              "        </td>\n" +
              "    </tr>\n" +
              "    </table>\n" +
              "</td>";
var parser=new DOMParser();
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(content,"text/xml");

var out = '';
var tdEl = xmlDoc.childNodes[0];
var count = tdEl.childNodes.length;
alert(count);
for(var i=0; i<count; i++) {
    out += serializer.serializeToString(tdEl.childNodes[i]);
}

console.log(out);
```